# css elements not showing up in chrome and IE9

Tags: css, wordpress, gallery

I have a small wordpress & css related problem regarding some elements that are not showing up properly or at all in IE9 and Chrome (latest version). However, in Firefox they appear ok.

On this page: http://next.lab501.ro/foto/sony-nex-3/3 in the sidebar (lower right) I have two elements (boxes), one is called lab501.ro (it's an RSS widget) that is not listing the items (their should be 10 items listed in that box) an below this one another box called Syndication that is not showing up at all.

This problem appears only on pages where I have a Gallery (standard wordpress not a plugin). If I remove the gallery the page renders correctly.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest checking (and fixing) the HTML is valid before doing anything else: the [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/) is a good place to start.  There seem to be quite a few issues, including two opening `<body>` tags.  The first one is followed by some lines with `//` at the start - maybe some PHP has been incorrectly commented?

Answer (score 1):

Your html ends abruptly right after the syndication box (there are no closing tags for the divs and body/html). This means you have a PHP error, which should be be debugged on a testing environment with php errors enabled.